# How to avoid duplicated rows from my result array when using where clause

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I need the names of the users that applied both the time I sent from my controller and time = double, so I need to display the results from this function but it duplicates the results, is there a way to resolve this?

The names of the users that picked time=double at a specific day, displays on everyday.

```
public function get_Shifts($day,$time){

    $this->db->select('user.fullname');
    $this->db->from('shifts');
    $this->db->join('user', 'shifts.user_id = user.id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('day=', $day);
    $this->db->where('time=',$time);
    $this->db->or_where('time=', $double);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

I tried adding this line and it didn't help:   `$this->db->distinct();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Codeigniter 3 you can use it's [Query Grouping](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping) functions:

> Query grouping allows you to create groups of WHERE clauses by
>   enclosing them in parentheses. This will allow you to create queries
>   with complex WHERE clauses

In your case, you can use:

```
$this->db->group_start()
  $this->db->where('day', $day);
  $this->db->where('time', $time);
$this->db->group_end()
$this->db->or_where('time', $double);
```

this will generate something like:

```
WHERE ( (`day` = '2020-04-23' AND `time` = '16:00'  ) OR `time` = true )
```

**edit to respond to comment:** to create an output like:  `WHERE ( (day = '2020-04-23' AND (time = '16:00' OR time = true ) )`

you use this approach:

```
$this->db->where('day', $day);
$this->db->group_start()
  $this->db->where('time', $time);
  $this->db->or_where('time', $double);
$this->db->group_end()
```

**note:** the correct way to use CI where() function is:

`$this->db->where('day', $day);` and not `$this->db->where('day=', $day);`

Comment: Okay I loved the idea of the group but Ideally, I need it to look like this


WHERE ( (`day` = '2020-04-23' AND (`time` = '16:00' OR `time` = true ) )

Can you help me with that, please?

Answer (score 0):

There should be an error while using

$this->db->where('day=', $day);

$this->db->where('time=',$time);

$this->db->or_where('time=', $double);

The right way to use where clause

$this->db->where('day', $day);

$this->db->where('time',$time);

$this->db->or_where('time', $double);

And if you are getting duplicate data for the above query, pass column name to the distinct like :-

$this->db->distinct('user.fullname');